# How to wait for request to finish in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am currently new to Jmeter, and trying to create a Jmeter script to test how long a request takes to process and complete.

a) Authenticate using Token - Complete
b) Post Request - Complete - Returns 200
c) Get Request - Partially Completed

C: I am Trying to get be able to monitor this request to find out when its either completed failed etc.

1. I have created the Http Request Sample with a Get Request
   [image]
2. I am able to get the Request 200 but it doesn't wait for completion

[image]

So running this in a console app, it waits for a certain time checking for status....

Is there a way to possibly write a code similar to the C# code in bean shell or groovy to wait. I was reading about while controller as well...

```
var result = WaitForBuildToComplete(dest, requestData, token, timeout);

 static string GetStatus(string path, Token token)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        AddToken(token, httpWebRequest);

        WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        string responseFromServer = "";
        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Close the response.  
        response.Close();
        return responseFromServer;
    }



static int WaitForBuildToComplete(string dest, RequestData requestData, Token token, int
```

timeout)
{
if (timeout <= 0) return 0;

```
        var path = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[dest]}/policy?id={requestData.id}";

        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        do
        {
            var status = GetStatus(path, token);
            var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(status);
            var requestStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestStatus>(msg);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestStatus.DllUrl))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nResult dll at: {requestStatus.DllUrl}");
                return 0;
            }
            if (requestStatus.Status.ToUpper() == "FAILED")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nFAILED");
                Console.WriteLine(requestStatus.Message);
                return -1;
            }

            if (requestStatus.Status.ToUpper() == "FAILED_DATA_ERROR")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nFAILED_DATA_ERROR");
                Console.WriteLine(requestStatus.Message);
                return -1;
            }

            if (requestStatus.Status.ToUpper() == "NOT_NEEDED")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nNOT_NEEDED");
                Console.WriteLine(requestStatus.Message);
                return -1;
            }

            Console.Write(".");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        } while ((DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds < timeout);
        Console.WriteLine("Time out waiting for dll.");
        return -1;
    }
```

I started by looking at JSR223 Sampler but wanted to see if there is a better and easier way to accomplish this.

```
List<String> sendRequest(String url, String method, Map<String,Object> body) {


    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(2000)
            .setSocketTimeout(3000)
            .build();

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(body), "UTF-8");


    HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create(method)
            .setConfig(requestConfig)
            .setUri(url)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
            .setEntity(entity)
            .build();
            
   String req = "REQUEST:" + "\n" + request.getRequestLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
            request.getAllHeaders() + "\n" + EntityUtils.toString(entity) + "\n";
            

    HttpClientBuilder.create().build().withCloseable {httpClient ->

        httpClient.execute(request).withCloseable {response ->

            String res = "RESPONSE:" + "\n" + response.getStatusLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
                    response.getAllHeaders() + "\n" +
                    (response.getEntity() != null ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : "") + "\n";

            System.out.println(req + "\n"  + res );
            
            return Arrays.asList(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```

List sendGet(String url, Map<String,String> body) {

```
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(2000)
            .setSocketTimeout(3000)
            .build();

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = RequestBuilder.get()
            .setConfig(requestConfig)
            .setUri(url)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    body.forEach({key, value -> requestBuilder.addParameter(key, value)});
    
    HttpUriRequest request = requestBuilder.build();

    String req = "REQUEST:" + "\n" + request.getRequestLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
            request.getAllHeaders() + "\n";

    HttpClientBuilder.create().build().withCloseable {httpClient ->

        httpClient.execute(request).withCloseable {response ->

            String res = "RESPONSE:" + "\n" + response.getStatusLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
                    response.getAllHeaders() + "\n" +
                    (response.getEntity() != null ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : "") + "\n";

            System.out.println(req + "\n"  + res );
            return Arrays.asList(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach which is normally used in JMeter is placing your request under the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) which will be checking the `Status` value which in its turn can be fetched from the response using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) so the request will be retried unless the "Status" changes to some value which you expect (or times out)

If you place the whole construction under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) you will get the whole time for the status to change.

Example test plan outline:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dmitri!!! i will try this and get back to you. Is there a way to test for multiple status within the same while controller?

Comment: You can put whatever expression you want into the "Condition" input, for example if you go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) you can use any number of expressions, just make sure that it evaluates to `true` or `false`. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to get familiarized with the concept of Groovy scripting in JMeter